# Is $(x^2y,xy^2)$ log smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, flatness, smoothness, log-geometry

Consider the map
$$f:\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C^2$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto(x^2y,xy^2)$$
We can view $f$ as induced by the map of monoids $g:\mathbb Z^2_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb Z^2_{\geq 0}$ given by the matrix $(\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\cr 1&2\end{smallmatrix})$.  Thus $f$ is a map of log schemes.

> Is $f$ log smooth?

If I understand Proposition 6.1 from https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9406004 correctly, the answer is supposed to be yes, since $\ker g$ and $(\operatorname{coker} g)_{\mathrm{tors}}$ are both finite.

On the other hand, log smooth maps are supposed to be flat, and flat maps are open.  Thus if $f$ were log smooth it would have to be open.  But it is not open: $(0,0)$ is in the image of $f$, but $(0,a)$ is not whenever $a\ne 0$.

Comment: I'm not an expert on log geometry,  so you may want to wait for an actual expert to weight in.  I thought flatness wasn't necessarily implied by log smoothness. At least that would resolve your apparent contradiction.

Comment: Interesting.  If that turns out to be the case, I would be interested to know if there are known properties (of independent significance) which are satisfied by maps like $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ but not $(x,y)\mapsto(x^2y,xy^2)$ or $(x,y,z)\mapsto(xy,xz)$.

Comment: Well Kato, in his foundational paper "Logarithmic structures of Fontaine-Illusie" gives a criterion   (Cor. 4.5): a [log] smooth *integral* morphism is flat. Presumably integrality (whose definition can be found there) fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is smooth.  For a log map to have good "fiber bundle properties", one needs more than smoothness.  Rather, one needs the relevant maps of monoids to be **exact** in the sense of Kato.  A reference is Nakayama--Ogus "Relative rounding in toric and logarithmic geometry" [Mathscinet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2740645) [Journal](https://msp.org/gt/2010/14-4/p09.xhtml).

Answer (score 3):

*Warning: I'm not an expert on logarithmic geometry.*

According to Proposition 4.1.2. of Ogus' *Lectures on Logarithmic Algebraic Geometry*, a log smooth morphism (of fine log schemes) is *log* flat. Log flatness is defined in Definition 4.1.1. Evidently, log flatness does not imply classical flatness. However, the same proposition says that log flatness *does* imply classical flatness (and is in fact equivalent to it!) if the morphism is strict.

We can confirm that $f$ is not strict using Proposition 1.2.4: Let $\theta$ be the monoid homomorphism $\Bbb N^2\to \Bbb N^2$ given by $\begin{bmatrix}2 &1\\1 &2\end{bmatrix}$. This map is already logarithmic since neither side has any units other than 0. However, $\theta$ is not an isomorphism and is therefore not strict. Hence, $f$ is not strict.